# Aggregate after join without duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

Consider this query:

```
select
   count(p.id),
   count(s.id),
   sum(s.price)
from 
   (select * from orders where <condition>)   as s,
   (select * from products where <condition>) as p
where 
   s.id = p.order;
```

There are, for example, 200 records in products and 100 in orders (one order can contain one or more products).

I need to join then and then:

1. count products (should return 200)
2. count orders (should return 100)
3. sum by one of orders field (should return sum by 100 prices)

The problem is after join **p** and **s** has same length and for **2)** I can write *count(distinct s.id)*, but for **3)** I'm getting duplicates (for example, if sale has 2 products it sums price twice) so sum works on entire 200 records set, but should query only 100.

Any thoughts how to *sum* only distinct records from joined table but also not ruin another selects?

Example, joined table has

```
id sale price
0  0    4
0  0    4
1  1    3
2  2    4
2  2    4
2  2    4
```

So the **sum(s.price)** will return:

```
4+4+3+4+4+4=23
```

but I need:

```
4+3+4=11
```

Comment: If you add example data and expected output it will be much clearer

Comment: Why would a "products" table have an `order` id in it?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: That was my thinking exactly. Confusing.

Comment: Sorry fot not clear explanation. Of course, this sample is much simplified and there are many other fields in both tables. I didn't want to add an overhead to question.
Product has reference to order due to @ManyToOne relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `products` table is really more of an "order lines" table, then the query would make sense.  You can do what you want by in several ways.  Here I'm going to suggest conditional aggregation:

```
select count(distinct p.id), count(distinct s.id),
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then s.price end)
from (select o.* from orders o where <condition>) s join
     (select p.*, row_number() over (partition by p.order order by p.order) as seqnum
      from products p
     where <condition>
     ) p
     on s.id = p.order;
```

Normally, a table called "products" would have one row per product, with things like a description and name.  A table called something like "OrderLines" or "OrderProducts" or "OrderDetails" would have the products within a given order.

Comment: It worked like a charm. I need to waste some time on 'window functions'... Seems it is worth it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not interested in single product records, but only in their number. So join the aggregate (one record per order) instead of the single rows:

```
select
  count(*) as count_orders,
  sum(p.cnt) as count_products,
  sum(s.price)
from orders as s
join 
(
  select order, count(*) as cnt 
  from products 
  where <condition> 
  group by order
) as p on p.order = s.id
where <condition>;
```

Comment: I need to make a filter first because of performance consideration (both tables have 40kk+ records). Thanks anyway.

Comment: What? By aggregating products I join *less* records and have therefore a *smaller* intermediate result. The dbms should hence be *faster* doing this. If it doesn't, I would blame this on postgres. The query as written should be about as fast as possible for the given task.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is with table design. You currently have no way of knowing the price of a product if there were no sales on it. Price should be in the product table. A product cost a certain price. Then you can count all the products of a sale and also get the total price of the sale.

Also why are you using subqueries. When you do this no indexes will be used when joining the two subqueries. If your joins are that complicated use views. In most databases they can indexed

Comment: I use indexes in both tables. These tables are just for sample (much more fieds in production). Sorry for confusion.